# Как сделать обнаружение объектов на картинке CV2 Python

Tags: python, изображения, машинное-обучение, opencv, поиск

Я разрабатываю программу, которая призвана автоматизировать построение мнемосхем по скриншотам. И сейчас у меня две проблемы, которые я не знаю как решить и прошу помочь мне советом.
У меня есть изображение со скриншотом мнемосхемы. На нём отображены промышленные объекты и линии потоков между ними. Вот кусочек для примера:

[image: Часть исходного изображения]

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы каждый объект обводился рамочкой, вот так:

[image: Вид изображения с обведёнными объектами - как должно быть]

Это нужно для того, чтобы в дальнейшем передать каждый из найденных отдельных объектов на обученную нейросеть, которая должна будет определить к какому классу принадлежит этот тот или иной объект. После классификации будет дальнейшая обработка и построение мнемосхемы.
Сейчас я делаю обработку изображения в 2 этапа.
Сперва, я пытаюсь обнаружить и удалить линии потоков - горизонтальные и вертикальные, путём замены цвета пикселей. У меня получается вот такая картина:

[image: Рисунок с удалёнными горизонтальными и вертикальными линиями]

А уже второй этап - обнаружение контуров и обведение их рамкой. Вот что у меня получается:

[image: Текущий результат обнаружения контуров]

Как видно - результат совсем не соответствует тому, что мне нужно получить в конечном итоге.
Я так думаю, что всё делло именно в линиях потоков. Ведь когда я делаю обнаружение контуров, у меня всё изображение преобразуется в чёрно-белое, и линии по сути сливаются с объектами. И не смотря на то, что я линии перекрашиваю в цвет фона (возможно, что близкий цвет, но не в точности - я определяла в графическом редакторе), они, видимо, остаются видимыми.
И вот я никак не могу придумать как решить эту задачу - как же мне сделать так, чтобы выделялись только контуры объектов, а линии потоков пока не учитывались. Может вы можете мне чем-то помочь в этом вопросе?

Comment: как составляются эти мнемосхемы? очевидно в каком-то приложении, может легче использовать файлы сохранений от этого приложения? или у вас есть доступ только с изображениям?

Comment: Александр, у меня есть доступ только к изображениям. Я не знаю как они получаются. Их видят операторы на установках по переработке сырья. Они делали скриншоты со своих рабочих компьютеров и сохраняли их в картинки.

Comment: вы можете привести свой код?

Comment: https://github.com/RZKsenia/BDRV/blob/master/BDRV_Scripts/MainScript.py

Comment: ваш репозиторий не общедоступен,у меня нет доступа к нему

Comment: Александр, я переделала на публичный доступ. Попробуйте ещё раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: насколько я понял, вам нужно определять отдельные объекты (их контуры)?

Comment: что и как запускать-то?

Answer (score 1):

Я сама смогла решить проблему. Я воспользовалась заменой цветов пикселей в линиях, соединяющих объекты. Это позволило получить каждый объект в отдельности.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/492304)

Comment: @DaemonHK, это явно ответ, а не дополнение к вопросу.